# Niveles de Usuario con Sesiones HTML + PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Seré breve y conciso, quiero crear un sistema que tenga un menú según el nivel de usuario establecido, Ejemplo Administrador - Usuario Comunes..., este debe contar con su cambiar contraseña etc... ese no es el problema.**

La cosa es que me he visto muchísimos tutoriales y enseñan a utilizar las sesiones pero sigo sin entender muy bien el como crear lo que necesito, ya que realizar un Sistema de Inicio de Sesión lo recreo, pero luego no me sirve de nada en las otras paginas, porque solo me redirecciona a una sola, y necesito que eso sea validado en todas las partes del menú que tiene.

No entiendo muy bien como hacerlo, pero básicamente quiero que index.php me redireccione cuando valide que ese usuario exista y tenga esa contraseña vaya a dashboard.php (Dependiendo de su nivel de usuario mostrará el menú, y la pantalla de inicio), y cada sección del menu, como por ejemplo pagina1.php, pagina2.php, sean de cada usuario.

Intento pero no me resulta y al final la variable no termina de ir. Utilizo la forma de Modelo Vista Controlador...

Si me explican o me envían donde puedo aprender a hacer esto lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno antes que nada es necesario saber como estas armando tus páginas (la vista), no es bueno tener el HTML mezclado con PHP, aún más si trabajas con sesiones. Siempre lo ideal es armar tu HTML con PHP y al final realizar un solo echo con todo tu HTML.

Cuando trabajas con sesiones en todos lados debes tener al inicio de tu código PHP:

```
session_start();
```

Sin embargo, cuando tienes includes varios en tu código puede llegar a llamarse más de una vez lo que produce un warning o error, poreso siempre prefiero validar antes.

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
      session_start(); 
    }
```

Cuando se inicia sesión se debe declarar las variables de sesiones pertinentes.

```
<?php
/* login.php */
/* Importante que sea lo primero que se ponga */
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
  session_start(); 
} 
/*....

validacion en la bd si existe la combinacion usuario / contraseña

...*/

/*si login es correcto */
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 $_SESSION['usertype'] = $usertype;//ejemplo: Administrador, Usuario, Cliente,...
```

Luego ya puedes validar si existe el usuario o si el usuario

```
<?php
/* index.php */
/* Importante que sea lo primero que se ponga */
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
  session_start(); 
} 
/* Si un usuario existe redirige al dashboard ...*/
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  header('Location: dashboard.php');
  exit();
}else{
/* Si no existe el usuario se redirecciona al login ...*/
  header('Location: login.php');
  exit();
}
```

Ya para validar los niveles de usuarios necesarios puedes hacerlo cuando quieras mientras estes armando tu html:

```
<?php
/* dashboard.php */
/* Importante que sea lo primero que se ponga */
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
  session_start(); 
} 
/* armas el menu ...*/
$header = "<html><head></head><body>";

$menu = "<ul>";
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['usertype'])){
/*Validas los niveles de cada usuario*/

  switch($_SESSION['usertype']){
    case 1://Administrador
      $menu .= "<li>Menu Administrador</li>";
      break;
    case 2://Usuario
      $menu .= "<li>Menu Usuario</li>";
      break;
    case 3://Cliente
      $menu .= "<li>Menu Cliente</li>";
      break;

  }
$menu .= "</ul>";    
}else{

    /* Si no existe el usuario se redirecciona al login ...*/
      header('Location: login.php');
      exit();
}

$footer = "</body></html>";

echo $header.$menu.$footer;
```

Nunca olvidar generar una página de cerrar sesion con

```
session_destroy();
session_unset();
```

Este es un ejemplo muy a la rápida, espero que te sirva para aclarar algunas dudas y no generar más. Saludos